# Gitlab - "Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key" on a valid key

Tags: ssh, windows-7, git, putty

I need some help with keys.

On my windows 7 machine I have created a pair of keys using Puttygen in order to connect to a private gitlab site.

In the gitlab I've added my public key to my profile.
I've connected to the server using Putty in order the cache the server fingerprint, and added GIT_SSH env variable.

On my project folder I've init the git repo, commited the changes, loaded my private key using Pageant and pushed to the server.
Everything worked as exepected - I was able to push the changes.

My problem - I wanted to use another Windows 7 machine to work on my project, I've tried using the same steps, but every time when I try to push i get:

`"Server refused public-key signature despite accepting key!"`

What am I doing wrong, what should I check?

Thanks for the help

**Update:**

I've looked at **etc/var/auth.log** on my server -
When I try to connect with the "refused machine", I see those lines:

```
localhost sshd[6979]: error: hash mismatch
localhost sshd[6979]: error: Received disconnect from *IP-of-router*: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

What or where can I get more information about this error?

**Update 2:**

The refused machine is connected to an ISP that uses web filtering. The ISP uses [www.netspark.com](http://www.netspark.com), my guess is that it is related to the problem and my private key being changed or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the refused machine was behind a company firewall.
I've asked the IT to exclude my gitlab server and that solved the problem

Hope this info will help others in the future

Answer (score -2):

go to /etc/ssh
cd /etc/ssh/
nano sshd_config
change this PermitRootLogin No to PermitRootLogin without-password
and systemctl restart sshd

*corrected nano ssh_config to nano sshd_config

Comment: It's worth nothing that the above suggested change makes for a less secure configuration (by allowing a root login where none was allowed before).  And as the OP didn't mention attempting to login as root, I'm not sure that the suggested change would help.